# Can GPIO mode be changed at once for more than one pin?

Tags: pi-2, c, pigpio

I'm currently trying to understand the [pigpio library](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) and I found it supports reading from and writing to more than one GPIO pin at once. However can it do the same with pin mode?

I'm asking the question because I am also trying to write a program to test a graphics display (that is powered in 3.3v). The latter uses a 8080-like communication bus, i.e. there are 3 control lines (outputs) but data is read from and written to the same 8 bus lines so I'd need to set 8 GPIO lines as inputs or outputs at different times.

The display expects commands and parameters. When reading from the display, I must write an 8-bit data, pulse the WR line low, set the 8 GPIO lines as input before I can pulse the RD line low and read what's on the 8 GPIO lines.

So is it possible to control 8 GPIO pins as input/output in one go? Or do they have to be set individually?

The device is a Raspberry Pi 2 model B.

---

**EDIT**: I also took a look at [BCM2835 library](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/index.html) and looking at the code it seems it might be possible though the 32-bit word that controls GPIO pins is split into bit fields, each field being 3 bits wide, due to the many possible pin configurations:

```
/* Function select
// pin is a BCM2835 GPIO pin number NOT RPi pin number
//      There are 6 control registers, each control the functions of a block
//      of 10 pins.
//      Each control register has 10 sets of 3 bits per GPIO pin:
//
//      000 = GPIO Pin X is an input
//      001 = GPIO Pin X is an output
//      100 = GPIO Pin X takes alternate function 0
//      101 = GPIO Pin X takes alternate function 1
//      110 = GPIO Pin X takes alternate function 2
//      111 = GPIO Pin X takes alternate function 3
//      011 = GPIO Pin X takes alternate function 4
//      010 = GPIO Pin X takes alternate function 5
//
// So the 3 bits for port X are:
//      X / 10 + ((X % 10) * 3)
*/
void bcm2835_gpio_fsel(uint8_t pin, uint8_t mode)
{
    /* Function selects are 10 pins per 32 bit word, 3 bits per pin */
    volatile uint32_t* paddr = bcm2835_gpio + BCM2835_GPFSEL0/4 + (pin/10);
    uint8_t   shift = (pin % 10) * 3;
    uint32_t  mask = BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_MASK << shift;
    uint32_t  value = mode << shift;
    bcm2835_peri_set_bits(paddr, value, mask);
}
```

So it looks like setting the mode for multiple pins is possible but it requires determining which bank to address first. If the 8 GPIO pins are fixed then the mask can be set in much fewer steps than setting all 8 pins one by one.

Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pigpio **does not** support setting the mode of multiple GPIO in one operation.

You would need to write your own code.  The pigpio implementation is as follows.

```c
int gpioSetMode(unsigned gpio, unsigned mode)
{
   int reg, shift, old_mode;

   DBG(DBG_USER, "gpio=%d mode=%d", gpio, mode);

   CHECK_INITED;

   if (gpio > PI_MAX_GPIO)
      SOFT_ERROR(PI_BAD_GPIO, "bad gpio (%d)", gpio);

   if (mode > PI_ALT3)
      SOFT_ERROR(PI_BAD_MODE, "gpio %d, bad mode (%d)", gpio, mode);

   reg   =  gpio/10;
   shift = (gpio%10) * 3;

   old_mode = (gpioReg[reg] >> shift) & 7;

   if (mode != old_mode)
   {
      switchFunctionOff(gpio);

      gpioInfo[gpio].is = GPIO_UNDEFINED;
   }

   gpioReg[reg] = (gpioReg[reg] & ~(7<<shift)) | (mode<<shift);

   return 0;
}
```

There are six 32-bit registers used to read/write the mode, GPIO Alternate function select register 0 through 5.

Register 0 for GPIO 0-9, 1 for GPIO 10-19, 2 for GPIO 20-29, 3 for GPIO 30-39, 4 for GPIO 40-49, and 5 for GPIO 50-53.

You need to preserve the settings of any GPIO you don't want to alter when you update one or more GPIO within a register.

Comment: Ah, thanks *a lot* Joan! That's *exactly* the information I needed.